# Markers hidden by axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, markers

Some data I have to plot have coordinates such as (20,**0**), (10,**0**), etc... Basically some of the points belong to the x-axis.

The problem is, these points are hidden by the axis; i.e. the markers are behind the line and therefore cannot be seen properly.

Here is an example of my figure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNcob.png

Does anybody have an idea to solve this problem? I am running out of idea...

Thanks.

Viktor

Comment: Why don't you set the data limits so the axes start at -1 or some such value instead of 0?

Comment: You really need to post your code so we can see how you are generating the plot and if there is something you're doing wrong. Without looking at anything I can only say maybe to extend your domain for y such that it would go to -1 so the points on 0 do not get cut off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib "snaps" plot limits to "whole" (factors of 2, 5, 10, 100, etc) numbers, by default.  This often means that your data may wind up on the boundary of the plot.

`ax.margins` allows you to add a padding factor before this autoscaling for the plot is calculated.  It's a quick way to avoid the problem of points on the plot boundary.

As a quick example of the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = [0, 10, 20], [10, 0, 0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'ko')
plt.show()
```

[image]

And an easy solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = [0, 10, 20], [10, 0, 0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'ko')

# Pad by 5% of the data range before autoscaling:
ax.margins(0.05)

plt.show()
```

[image]